# How can I use CSS3 animations with position:relative and without overusing the CPU?

Tags: css, css-position

I'm trying to create a wheel-of-fortune type of animation. I'm using 4 divs, one on top of the other (with transparent PNGs) for the whole design.

Now I'm trying to animate it using CSS3 but I ran into an issue: whenever one of the #rotate div's ancestors in relatively positioned then the CPU jumps to over 70% (I'm using a Macbook Pro 2.3Ghz).

**In the example below if I set #main to position:absolute then it works just fine, not using any more CPU than a regular page does. But when changing to position:relative it jumps to over 70% CPU usage.**

Does anybody know how to work around this issue?

Here's an example of my code (for readability I only wrote the -webkit specific CSS, but the original source has the corresponding CSS for every major modern browser):

```
<html>

  <body>
  <style>

  @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
      from {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
  }

  #background {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("background.png");
    width: 604px;
    height: 604px;;
  }

  #bottom {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("wheel_bg.png");
    width: 604px;
    height: 604px;;
  }

  #top {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("wheel_top.png");
    width: 604px;
    height: 604px;;
  }

  #rotate
  {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 15s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    background: url("wheel_rotate.png");
    width: 604px;
    height: 604px;
    left: 0;
  }

  #main {
    position: relative; //here's the problem
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
  }

  </style>

  <div id="main">
    <div id="background">
    </div>  
    <div id="rotate">
    </div>
    <div id="top">
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
    </div>
  </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your document is reflowing with the rotations, which is very taxing to the CPU. I'd try to specify a width and height on `#main`, or place an additional wrapper over main and position relative that.

Other than that, you can also take advantage of the GPU by using 3D CSS transforms, just change this:

```
 @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
      from {
          -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg);
      }
      to {
          -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,360deg);
      }
  }
```

But I'm afraid that—as long as the document is reflowing—you might not see significant CPU gains from this technique, just smoother frame rates.

For more info on reflows, http://code.google.com/speed/articles/reflow.html